# Create and manipulate On-demand collections of runtime controls

Tags: vba, excel, collections

This is my first post. I've tried to find a similar topic but could not find any.

I am fairly new to VBA and I am learning as I try to create a  file that helps plan cutting parts of a major piece.

Since Excel VBA does not allow to draw shapes or lines, I am using labels with a border to create rectangles.

The rectangles represent the cuts to be made.

My main form has this look:

[Main Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqpSa.png)

As you can see in the image, in the area signaled with a red rectangle, the big piece with 1600 mm (in this example) will have seven 60 mm cuts.

My problem started when I tried to add different cuts to my cutting planning.
As I accept a cut, it goes to the cutting queue, and a new cut can be defined, as shown in the below image:

[Second cut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gVfX.png)

The problem is that the first cut should stay there. I realized that I have to use **Collections** and most probably **Classes** for that.
This is especially important as I want, in the queue, to be able to move each line up and down the queue or even erase a line (and reflect it in my "drawing").

The code for now is far too extensive to add it here, but I managed to put some in functions that will go bellow. Some names are in portuguese, but I don't think it presents a problem.

Here I create the cuts defined by *Largura:* and *Cortes reais:*

```
Option Explicit
Public iCuts As Integer
Public Labels As Collection
Public newLabel As Object
Public bRecalculate As Boolean


Sub DrawCuts(NCuts As Integer, CutWidth As Double, TotalWidth)
Dim OriginX, OriginY As Integer
Dim labelCounter As Long
Dim labelCollection As New Collection


OriginX = 372
OriginY = 24
CutWidth = Multiplier(CutWidth, TotalWidth)

    For labelCounter = 0 To NCuts - 1
        Set newLabel = frmPlanning.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Corte" &     labelCounter, True)
        With newLabel
            .ControlTipText = .Name 'labelCounter + 1
            .Left = OriginX + CutWidth * labelCounter
            .Width = CutWidth
            .Height = 48
            .Top = OriginY
            .BackColor = &HFFFFFF
            .BorderStyle = 1
            .TextAlign = 2
            .Font.Size = 6
            .Caption = iCuts
        End With
        iCuts = iCuts + 1
    Next
    iCuts = iCuts - 1
End Sub
```

And in the next SUB I adapt the cuts to the size of the main piece, defined by *Larg. bobine:*

```
Sub Dim_Labels(Cuts As Integer, CutWidth As Double, RollWidth As Double,     RollLeft As Double)

    With frmPlanning.lCutWidth
        .Caption = CutWidth * Cuts
        .Width = Cuts * Multiplier(CutWidth, RollWidth)
    End With

    With frmPlanning.lCutLeft
        .Caption = RollLeft
        .Left = 372 + Cuts * Multiplier(CutWidth, RollWidth) 
        .Width = 320 - Cuts * Multiplier(CutWidth, RollWidth) 
    End With

    frmPlanning.lRollWidth = RollWidth
End Sub
```

I have tried to put this in a collection but not only I receive all sorts of errors but I also cannot create different collections for each set of cuts on order to move each set independently.

I know this has to due with my lack of understanding of how collections and classes work, but I really am stuck and cannot go forward with this and need some help if you can give it.

I couldn't find a way, but I can provide the excel file to help you better understand the problem, if there is a way.

Thank you.
Júlio

Comment: Do I summarize this correctly when I say that you need:

A. `X` cuts with width `w`, where TotalCutsWidth (X*w) does not exceed the big block (red rectangle) width (TotalWidth)
B. Then add a second (third, fourth) array of such cuts (say: Y) to be added a number of times.
C. The TotalCutsWidth for all groups combined of cuts should not exceed "TotalWidth" either?
In summary: The user can define exactly how many pieces of which width they want out of the total red rectangle, and this should be drawn with labels in that top right box?

Comment: @RikSportel, thank you for your reply. Yes but not sure I understood correctly your point B and to clarify, the second, third,... cuts can all have different widths, though the cuts inside the batch will all have the same width.

Comment: Yeah that was point B. But after adding all the "batches", they altogether need to fit in the big box correct?

Comment: Yes, at the end they all must fit the big box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think this is what you're after. Note that it's not the cleanest code, but it does the drawing bits on a userform in isolation.

First, I stored the OriginX and OriginY in the Userform itself - After all, it should control where the drawing should start. Userform code:

```
Public OriginX As Integer
Public OriginY As Integer
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    OriginX = 20
    OriginY = 20
End Sub
```

Next, I created a class "BigBox" for the red rectangle you had. It has a Height, a Width, and on initialization it will add it's label to the Userform. 
(Note that putting the label on the form in this way is *bad practice* - The class shouldn't have to be aware of where to draw it. However - for answering your question this isn't immediately relevant.)

BigBox Class:

```
Private p_width As Integer
Private p_height As Integer
Private p_label As MSForms.Label
Public Property Let Width(value As Integer)
    p_width = value
    p_label.Width = p_width
End Property
Public Property Get Width() As Integer
    Width = p_width
End Property
Public Property Let Height(value As Integer)
    p_height = value
    p_label.Height = p_height
End Property
Public Property Get Height() As Integer
    Height = p_height
End Property
Public Property Get Label() As MSForms.Label
    Set Label = p_label
End Property
Private Sub Class_Initialize() 'This bit is bad practice, but it works:
    Set p_label = frmPlanning.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "BigBox", True)
    p_label.Left = frmPlanning.OriginX
    p_label.Top = frmPlanning.OriginY
    p_label.BorderColor = Red
    p_label.BorderStyle = 1
End Sub
```

Next, I created a class "Cut" that can be used in a collection with the cuts, so when you need to redraw, you have them stored / they don't get forgotten:

Cut class:

```
Private p_width As Integer
Private p_height As Integer
Public Property Let Width(value As Integer)
    p_width = value
End Property
Public Property Get Width() As Integer
    Width = p_width
End Property
Public Property Let Height(value As Integer)
    p_height = value
End Property
Public Property Get Height() As Integer
    Height = p_height
End Property
```

Next, I isolated the "Cuts" and the "Labels" collections, since the labels need to be deleted and redrawn when you add a second batch. The following routine

- Makes sure the Cuts collection and the labels collections exist
- Shows the form (modeless, so code execution continues)
- Creates the BigBox and sets the height and width. All cuts will take the height from here.
- Adds cuts a couple of times.
- Has the "add cut" routine also execute the drawing routine.

Module1 code:

```
Option Explicit
Public bb As BigBox
Public cuts As Collection
Public cutLabels As Collection
Public totalCutsWidth As Integer
Public piece As Cut
Sub test2()
    If cuts Is Nothing Then
        Set cuts = New Collection
    End If
    If cutLabels Is Nothing Then
        Set cutLabels = New Collection
    End If

    frmPlanning.Show vbModeless

    Set bb = New BigBox
    bb.Height = 100
    bb.Width = 500
    AddCuts 5, 20
    AddCuts 10, 10
    AddCuts 7, 50
End Sub

Sub AddCuts(numberOfCuts As Integer, widthOfCuts As Integer)
Dim i As Integer
If numberOfCuts <= 0 Then Exit Sub
For i = 1 To numberOfCuts
    Set piece = New Cut
    piece.Width = widthOfCuts
    piece.Height = bb.Height
    totalCutsWidth = totalCutsWidth + widthOfCuts
    If totalCutsWidth <= bb.Width Then
        cuts.Add piece
    End If
Next i
DrawCuts
End Sub
Sub DrawCuts()
Dim i As Integer
Dim OffsetX As Integer
Dim newLabel As MSForms.Label

OffsetX = 0

For i = cutLabels.Count To 1 Step -1
    frmPlanning.Controls.Remove "Corte" & i
    cutLabels.Remove i
Next i

i = 0
OffsetX = frmPlanning.OriginX
For Each piece In cuts
    i = i + 1
    Set newLabel = frmPlanning.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Corte" & i, True)
    With newLabel
        .ControlTipText = .Name
        .Left = OffsetX
        .Width = piece.Width
        .Height = piece.Height
        .Top = frmPlanning.OriginY
        .BackColor = &HFFFFFF
        .BorderStyle = 1
        .TextAlign = 2
        .Font.Size = 6
        .Caption = i
        OffsetX = OffsetX + piece.Width
    End With
    cutLabels.Add newLabel
Next piece
End Sub
```

Note that add cuts makes sure that the cuts still fit within the big box, and that the drawing of the cuts is separated from that. Also, if the next piece wouldn't fit in the box anymore it won't be added. I.e. if the big box has width 500, and you add 10 cuts of width 25, and then 11 cuts of width 30, it will only add the first 8 of the second batch (10*25=250, 8*30=240, 240+250=490, so the 9th, 10th and 11th do not fit in the 500 total width, therefore will not be added.

Hope this helps and is enough information to merge into your existing solution.

Comment: Hi Rik. You are awesome just for the work you had. I think that I can handle it from here. I will try the code and get back to you as soon as I have it working on my file (hopefully). Thank you.

Comment: Hi @RikSportel, I am sorry for this late reply. I haven't had much time to look at it (priorities always changing!)... I have no words to thank you. The code works wonderfully. I had to make some minor changes to integrate it into the existing code but it worked just fine. With that I've also learned how classes and collections work, understanding them much better now. I still have some problems to solve but are more a matter of organizing my code than anything else. Thank you again for your help. Best regards.